# GCC: why does compiling a .hpp file gives different results than a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, gcc

Here I have a very simple Point class:

```
namespace wtf{

  template<typename T> class Point{

    public:
      T x;
      T y;

      Point(T xx, T yy): x(xx), y(yy) {};
  };

}
```

As a templated class, it is my understanding that there cannot be separate header/implementation files as usual.

If I name the file that contains this class `Point.cpp`, and compile it to a shared library as shown below, the file size is 5.6K, which seems reasonable. If I rename the file to `Point.hpp` (Or `.hxx` or `.h++`), however, the file size grows to 1.9M! Clearly `gcc` is processing these two file types differently!

Before I stripped this down to a MWE, there were additional standard lib includes (`sstream` and `iostream`), which brought the file size up to 11M! That also might give a little more of a clue about what is going on, though...

I am curious about what is actually happening here, and whether there are other ways that `gcc` treats header files and code files differently. Mostly I have used `gcc` 5.2.0, though the same thing happened with older versions.

I do understand that it is probably not typical to try and compile a header file, but since I *did* try and found a funny result, I would like to know what's going on!

Thanks!

EDIT: Removed image.

Comment: Why do you believe that the file size is only the binary generated from you source? BTW: Compiling a class definition to a shared lib is useless.

Comment: I don't believe that. In fact, I'm sure that is not the case! I don't know what else _is_ being included though, which is essentially what I am asking about. :)

As far as being useless, this is actually an implementation, not just a declaration. If it was more than a MWE, there would be more implementation there.

Comment: `gcc -v` can give more info. And please don't post images.

Comment: @RinRisson I guess you are creating a [precompiled header](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html) second time (somehow gcc detects that). Quite a different beast. The size raises drastically with nested includes since all defined objects are relevant.

Comment: I can't see anything which generate executable code here. Please read what a elf-file contains and use objdump to look into the details.

Comment: @ks1322 Thanks for the tip, I removed the image.

Comment: @freakish Turns out that was the case! Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus Good call... After I posted this I ran `nm`, which failed on the bad version. That should have been a big clue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tricked your compiler into naming the file `libPoint.so`, while in fact it's not a shared library.

#### TL;DR: You're making a *precompiled header*.

Which effectively means the compiler processes the entire header and saves it's own state to a file. Later, when you give it a `.c`/`.cpp` file which *starts with* `#include "Point.hxx"`, it loads the state from the precompiled header, so it doesn't need to process it again. Thus, your code compiles faster. *In a source file, only the first included header can benefit from this*.

If you remove `-o blah.so` from your command, GCC will name it `Point.hxx.gch`, which is the intended name for a precompiled header. In fact, GCC won't even find your PCH if it's named differently.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea! Is compiling a templated class into a shared library even a meaningful thing to do, then?

Comment: @RinRisson No, not really.